# NSPredicate for items in two-levels deep to-many relationship, w/o direct relationship

Tags: core-data, subquery, nspredicate, one-to-many, identifier

I'm trying to build a single `NSFetchRequest` predicate for the following (simplified) model:

[image]

- There is a simple to-many relationship between a `Category` and a number of `Brand`s.
- Each `Brand` then has a `modelNumbersData` property which is binary data, a serialisation of an array of `NSString` modelNumbers which are exposed in a transient property on the `Brand` objects.
- There is no *direct* relationship between `Brand`s and `Model`s. The relationship is that a `Model`'s `modelNumber` may be in a `Brand`'s `modelNumbers` transient property.

I would like to build an `NSPredicate` query to fetch **all of the `Model` objects under a particular `Category`**.

Fetching the `Model`s for a `Brand` is easy, I can do `"modelNumber IN $FETCH_SOURCE.modelNumbers"`. How do I now extend this query to originate with the category? It seems I need a `SUBQUERY`?

Furthermore, I am doing an `NSFetchRequest`, so unless I'm mistaken I need to start with `"SELF.modelNumber IN (...)"`, so that we select from all `Model`s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an update, if I first fetch ALL the `Model`s, I can filter for what I want with:

    `SUBQUERY(%@.brands, $brand, $brand.modelNumbers CONTAINS SELF.modelNumber).@count > 0`

But how can I combine this into a single step/query? Seems it needs to be the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got there first. For reference, the following works:

```
SUBQUERY(%@.brands, $brand, $brand.modelNumbers CONTAINS $modelNumber).@count > 0
```

I think the problem I was mostly having was neglecting the `.@count` component. Still don't *quite* understand this, but it seems to be necessary with all `SUBQUERY` statements.